# Bamboo: Override a runtime variable - build working directory?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, bamboo

I'd like to override the build working directory for my bamboo plan.

I noticed the it's always something like `<HOME>\<BUILD_PROJECT>-<BUILD-PLAN>-<JOB-KEY>`

I'd like to override the build directory so all the stages and jobs will use the same.

**Current Setup:**

```
STAGE 1
  JOB 1: build dir = C:\data\bamboo\agent5_1\xml-data\build-dir\PROJ-PLAN-S101
STAGE 2
  JOB 1: build dir = C:\data\bamboo\agent5_1\xml-data\build-dir\PROJ-PLAN-S201
  JOB 2: build dir = C:\data\bamboo\agent5_1\xml-data\build-dir\PROJ-PLAN-S202
```

**Current Setup:**

```
STAGE 1
  JOB 1: build dir = C:\data\bamboo\agent5_1\xml-data\build-dir\PROJ-PLAN-FOO
STAGE 2
  JOB 1: build dir = C:\data\bamboo\agent5_1\xml-data\build-dir\PROJ-PLAN-FOO
  JOB 2: build dir = C:\data\bamboo\agent5_1\xml-data\build-dir\PROJ-PLAN-FOO
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can or would want to use the same folder as it violates the multi-stage and concurrent job philosophy of Bamboo.

Multiple stages are separated by folder so that each build stage is isolated from the previous.  If you want to share files between the stages you will want to **use an artifact**.

Multiple jobs are separated by folder so that they can be run concurrently.  If the jobs were all in the same folder, this would not be possible due to permissions errors (especially on Windows).  If you don't care about the jobs running concurrently the two jobs in the second stage could be combined.

Since you want to build in the same folder on the same system, it sounds like this pipeline could be simplified to one stage with one job.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that jobs are supposed to run concrrently. Just that in my case, I know that all jobs will always run on the same agent and will not run concurrently. Reason why I don't want to put it in one job is because I want the other jobs to run if the previous fails. I'll take a look at artifact sharing.